# How to make multiple http requests in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am trying to user factory object to make multiple http requests. I have something like

```
angular.module('App').factory('myFactory', function($http, $q) {
    var service = {};

    service.setProduct = function(productObj) {
        _productObj = productObj;
    }

    service.makeRequest = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post('/api/product', _productObj).success(function(data){
            var id = data.id
            //I am not sure how to chain multiple calls by using promise.
            //$http.post('/api/details/, id).success(function(data) {
            //    console.log(data)
            //}
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function() {
            deferred.reject('error here');
        })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    return service;
});







angular.module('App').controller('productCtrl', ['$scope','$http','myFactory',
    function($scope, $http, myFactory) {
        myFactory.setProduct(productObj);
        myFactory.makeRequest()
            .then(function(data) {
               console.log(data) 
            }, function(data) {
               alert(data)
            })

    }
]);
```

I was able to use myfactory.makeRequest() to make one call but not sure how to chain multiple http requests. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to make sequential requests, then you need to chain promises. You don't even need to create your own `deferred` object - `$http.post` already returns a promise, so you could just `.then` it.

```
return $http.get("url1")
   .then(function(response){

     var nextUrl = response.data;
     return $http.get(nextUrl);
   })
   .then(function(response){

     var nextUrl = response.data;
     return $http.get(nextUrl);
   })
   .then(function(response){

     return response.data;
   });
```

`.success` is used for a more traditional non-promise approach

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8dQbHjdNi8yYmHP0vRkg?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Do some reading on promises. Remember that JS in asynchronous. You will need to make your next server call within the callback (the first .then function).